# TextField - How to disable the keyboard?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How the popping keyboard can be disabled when the TextField is pressed?
I want to have a DateTime picker instead.

(DatePicker is from pub.dev)

This is what I tried:

```
TextField(
   onTap: (){
   SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
                    DatePicker.showDatePicker(context,
                          showTitleActions: true,
                          minTime: DateTime(1940, 1, 1),
                          maxTime: DateTime.now(), 
                          onConfirm: (date) {
                            birth=date;
                        print('confirm $birth');
                      }, currentTime: DateTime.now());
                  },
                ),
```

Whenever the TextField is pressed, the keyboard is popping for a short time, after that it is replaced by DatePicker. I wish to make the keyboard not to pop at all. Many thanks.

Comment: So far I found something more: setting ```readOnly:true```. But there is still a difference in design

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and solved it setting the property keyboardType to TextInputType.none like bellow:

```
    TextField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.none,
      onTap: () {
        // Code of my showDatePicker
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are **not** going to allow user to enter/edit value using Soft Keyboard, then instead of [TextField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html), you can use [Text](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html) widget with [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) to open [DatePicker](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDatePicker.html).

Answer (score 0):

just set `enable` property to false in `InputDecoration` property of text Field

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration( enabled: false, ),
     onTap: (){
         SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
                DatePicker.showDatePicker(context,
                      showTitleActions: true,
                      minTime: DateTime(1940, 1, 1),
                      maxTime: DateTime.now(), 
                      onConfirm: (date) {
                        birth=date;
                    print('confirm $birth');
                  }, currentTime: DateTime.now());
              },
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply don't use Textfield use Container instead and Wrap it with Gesture Detector and inside your Container is the Date picked as Text

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: (){
   DatePicker.showPicker(context, 
      showTitleActions: true,
      minTime: DateTime(1940, 1, 1),
      maxTime: DateTime.now(),
      onConfirm: (date){
       setState((){
         birth = date;
      });
     },
     currentTime: DateTime.now()
   );
  }
  child: Container(
     child: Text("$birth")
  )
)
```